# Laravel blade override logo in layout depending on the view

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a Laravel layout which contains a very basic structure of the website, including a header with a logo.

Now I need to add a custom logo but on 3 specific pages only. I can simple duplicate the layout but the only difference between the two files will be just the logo.

Is there any way of loading the custom logo on the specific pages and the default logo in all the remaining pages?

The code in the layout file to display the logo is:

```
<img src="{{ asset('/images/logo.png') }}" class="logo"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need condition to determine default page and remaining pages. Do you have nay such condition?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a variable for the img source URL and have the default logo as a fallback

```
<img src="{{ $logo_url ?? asset('/images/logo.png') }}" class="logo"/>
```

On the pages that you want to override the logo, pass it to the view from your controller

```
$logo_url = asset('/images/custom_logo.png');

return view('some.view', compact('logo_url'));
```

On pages where you don't pass a custom logo, it will fallback to the default option

As an aside, if all the pages that need this custom logo are under the same section of the site you could use a view composer to set the logo based on which blade template is being rendered. So if the custom logo is for a section of a 'wiki' section of the site and all the views are win the same folder...

```
 View::composer('wiki.*', function ($view) {
      $view->with('logo_url', asset('/img/logo.png');
 });
```

Comment: Is there a way of setting this variable in the actual page, i.e. without setting it in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

I’d just make the logo a variable with a default value, and then set the variable in the views you want to override that logo:

```html
<!-- resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <header>
      <a href="{{ url('/') }}">
        <img src="{{ $logo ?? asset('img/default-logo.png') }}" alt="logo" />
      </a>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the views you want to override the logo:

```html
@extends('layouts.app', ['logo' => asset('img/custom-logo.png')])

{{-- Rest of view --}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, instead of @AlecJoy's option, it's easier and cleaner to use `@yield` with default value and `@section` in child views.

Layout view:

```
<img src="@yield('logo', asset('/images/logo.png'))" class="logo"/>
```

First page view:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('logo', asset('images/logo1.png'))
```

Second page view:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('logo', asset('images/logo2.png'))
```

Third page view:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('logo', asset('images/logo3.png'))
```

All you need to understand is here: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#defining-a-layout